# SQL Query to search for any variation of a first name and last name within a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of 1,700 names.  I need to search on those names within one column of a database and search on any variation and order of that name.  For example, if the name I'm searching on is John Smith, I need to search the column for any occurrence including 'John Smith', 'Smith John', 'Smith, John' etc.  I've tried many different variations on LIKE and IN, and wildcards in different spots, but am not getting the proper results.

Assuming the column is called 'Name' and the first 3 names are John Smith, Jane Doe, and Joe Johnson, what would be the syntax?

The closest I got was

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE Name LIKE 'John Smith'
OR Name LIKE 'Jane Doe'
OR Name LIKE 'Joe Johnson'
```

The problem with the above is that it doesn't return any results that contain Doe, Jane, for example.

Comment: What about variations of last names such as Smyth, Jonson and Johnston?

Comment: More advanced pattern matching is possible. For example

`Name LIKE '%Sm[iy]th%'`

Would match "Smith" or "Smyth" anywhere in the column text.

Comment: The request assumes the spelling of the names are known.  It's just that the column unfortunately has names stored in different formats and orders.

Comment: SQL does not use regular expressions, and it is not possible to use the pattern language to match an "optional" character (as in "Johnson" vs "Johns**t**on"). Matching both "Johnson" and "Johnston" probably necessitates a separate where clause: `Name LIKE '%Johnson%' or Name LIKE '%Johnston%'`

Answer (score 4):

I think this might do what you want:

```
where (name like '%John%' and name like '%Smith%') or
      (name like '%Jane%' and name like '%Doe%') or
      (name like '%Joe%' and name like '%Johnson%')
```

Comment: To add onto this, the LIKE keyword supports more advanced pattern matching than just the '%' wildcard: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - This seems to work ok only if there are no duplicate names. Once I introduced another person with the first name John, my results returned all records that have any variation of John in the name field, instead of only returning fields with John Smith, and John Doe, for example.

Comment: @Stpete111 . . . There are two conditions for each `or`.  Each should match only one name.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - certainly I would expect it to work that way.  However, it's very strange.  I'm seeing some results where Name has "John" but a completely different last name than Smith or Doe.  This only happens once I've introduced a name into the query which has the same first name as another.  I'll have to post an example.

Comment: @Stpete111 . . . You do realize that "John" matches "Johnson".  So, "Mary Johnson-Smith" would also match the first condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - sorry that's a bad example I gave.  I was using that example only for simplicity and privacy's sake.  The real names are Adam Harris and Adam Garvan.  With only Adam Harris as one of the 1,700 names, no issues - as soon as I introduce Adam Garvan into the query, the results bring back any record that has "Adam" in the name field.

Comment: @Stpete111 . . . Be careful about the parentheses around the condition.